# React js drag and drop functionality implementation

Tags: reactjs

i want to drag and drop added task division to the completed task division and vice versa. but could not find the solution yet in this code.

import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Main() {

```
//setting state here.
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

const [taskInput, setTaskInput] = useState('');
const [editedTaskText, setEditedTaskText] = useState('');
const [editedTaskIndex, setEditedTaskIndex] = useState(null);


const isUpdating = editedTaskIndex !== null;

//functionality for adding and updating tasks from creat-task division.
const addOrUpdateTask = () => {
    if (isUpdating) {
        if (taskInput.trim() !== '') {
            const updatedTasks = [...tasks];
            updatedTasks[editedTaskIndex] = taskInput;
            setTasks(updatedTasks);
            setTaskInput('');
            setEditedTaskText('');
            setEditedTaskIndex(null);
        } else {
            alert('Please enter a task before updating.');
        }
    } else if (taskInput.trim() !== '') {
        setTasks([...tasks, taskInput]);
        setTaskInput('');
    } else {
        alert('Please enter a task before adding.');
    }
};

//task-edit function
const editTask = (index) => {
    setEditedTaskText(tasks[index]);
    setEditedTaskIndex(index);
    setTaskInput(tasks[index]);
};

//delete task-function 
const deleteTask = (index) => {
    const updatedTasks = tasks.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
    setTasks(updatedTasks);
};

return (
    //main division holds two containers create-task and read-completed tasks.
    <div className="main">

        {/*create task div where task will be added in textbot */}
        <div className="create-task">
            <h1>Todos</h1>

            <input className="create-task-input" placeholder="Add a task here..."
                type="text"
                value={taskInput}
                onChange={(e) => setTaskInput(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button onClick={addOrUpdateTask} className="creat-task-button">
                {isUpdating ? 'Update' : 'Add Task'}
            </button>
        </div>

        {/* read-complete-task div where task will be read and moved to completed task */}
       
            <div className="read-complete-task">


                <div className="read-task">
                    <h2>My Tasks</h2>
                    {tasks.map((task, index) => (


                        <div className="added-task" key={index} >
                            <span>{task}</span>
                            <svg onClick={() => editTask(index)} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" className="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 16 16" >
                                <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z" />
                                <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z" />
                            </svg>
                            <svg onClick={() => deleteTask(index)} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" className="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6Z" />
                                <path d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1ZM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118ZM2.5 3h11V2h-11v1Z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    ))}

                </div>

                {/*completed task section , here all completed task will be displayed */}
                {/*by clicking the checkbox and hitting the undo button tasks will added back to read task div */}
                <div div className="completed-task" >
                    <h2>Completed Task</h2>

                </div>
            </div>
        
    </div>
)
```

}

i tried react-beautiful-dnd libarary and its packages but could not implemented yet what i want.